# DSolve gives complex function although the solution is a real one

Tags: differential-equations

I have a problem with the DSolve[] command in mathematica 8. Solving the the  following 4th order differential equation spits out a complex solution although it should be a real one. The equation is:

```
y''''[x] + a y[x] == 0
```

Solving this equation by hand yields a solution with only real parts. All constants and boundary conditions are also real numbers.

The solution I get by hand is:

```
y1[x_] = (C[5] E^(Power[a, (4)^-1]/Power[2, (2)^-1] x) + 
C[6] E^(-(Power[a, (4)^-1]/Power[2, (2)^-1]) x)) Cos[
Power[a, (4)^-1]/Power[2, (2)^-1]
x] + (C[7] E^(Power[a, (4)^-1]/Power[2, (2)^-1] x) + 
C[8] E^(-(Power[a, (4)^-1]/Power[2, (2)^-1]) x)) Sin[
Power[a, (4)^-1]/Power[2, (2)^-1] x];
```

Now I have to solve for the constants `C[5]...C[8]`. This arises a similar issue. I use the `Solve[]` command with the boundary conditions

```
Solve[{y1''[-c] == ic0, y1''[c] == ic0 , y1'''[-c] == ic1 , 
y1'''[c] == - ic1 }, {C[5], C[6], C[7], C[8]} ];
```

The constants `C[5]...C[8]` are now real if using `//Simplify` and complex if using `//FullSimplify`.

Any idea what the reasons are? The notebook with my calculations can be downloaded under: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4920002/DGL_4th_Order_with_own_solution.nb

In further work I have to use DSolve[] and I would like to understand the issue here.

Comment: 1. `DSolve[]` always treats all variables as complex; unless you tell, say, `FullSimplify[]` that `a` is real, you'll get the complex bits. 2. You've noticed that the characteristic equation of your DE has complex roots, yes?

Comment: Welcome at Mathematica.SE,user2214!. If you don't mind, could you try to focus your creative powers at conceiving a more rememberable username?

Comment: Changed my unsername :). Since I am new here I have a question. Is it not appropriate to crosspost in stackexchange and stackoverflow? Are these two webpages the same?

Comment: @J.M. : I know that my solution has four Eigenvalues , two sets of complex conjungated Eigenvalues. So I think that I should be able to get a real solution by using real boundary conditions and a real independent variable x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the reply I got from the *Mathematica* support team:

> Thank you for your prompt reply.
>
> Please find attached a small notebook which demonstrates using
>   [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html)
>   directly on the output of your first
>   [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)
>   expression to obtain a symbolic real-valued formula.
>
> The formula itself does contain imaginary values, but these zero each
>   other out as seen when the formula is evaluated numerically.
>   Unfortunately, the corresponding "hidden zero" in the imaginary
>   component cannot be eliminated by either of two typical techniques:
>
> (1) increasing the internal precision available to the
>   [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) function when
>   evaluating the formula numerically, or
>
> (2) using `FullSimplify` which is sometimes successful in removing
>   hidden zeros from symbolic formulas.
>
> The recommended approach in cases like this is to use the
>   [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html)
>   function, which will eliminate near-zero numerical values in any given
>   expression.
>
> For more information, please see the Possible Issues subsection of the
>   [`$MaxExtraPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%24MaxExtraPrecision.html) page.
>
> For details on the `Chop` function and how its behavior can be
>   customized, please see its corresponding [Documentation Center
>   page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Chop.html).
>
> Please let me know if you have any questions. Thank you.
>
> ```
> {sol} = DSolve[{y''''[x] + a y[x] == 0, y''[-c] == ic0, y''[c] == ic0,
>  y'''[-c] == ic1, y'''[c] == -ic1}, y[x], x];
>
> val = FullSimplify[sol, a > 0 && {ic0, ic1, c, x} \[Element] Reals]
>
> N[val]
> % // Chop
>
> Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 10000}, N[val]]
> % // Chop
> ```

Answer (score 10):

First, you can't say *the solution is a real one*, because in the generale case it is not. Take this function:

```
f[x_] := I*E^(-((a^(1/4) x)/Sqrt[2]))*Sin[(a^(1/4) x)/Sqrt[2]]
```

It so happens that it is not real (it's pure imaginary), and it is *a* solution to your differential equation:

[image]

Yes, the general form of the solution is thus complex. If you are only interested in real solutions, you have two options:

1. add some (real) initial conditions, so you get a fully specified *real* solution after some simplification:

   [image]
2. analyse the general solution to find out how it can be factor into real and complex parts:

   [image]

   The first part of that expression is the general equation of the *real* solutions to your differential equation.

Comment: Hi thanks for your explanations.

If I try to Solve the constants C[1]...C[5] for only the real part with my real boundary conditions I get an empty set. 

my boundary conditions are:
y''[-c] == ic0, y''[c] == ic0 , y'''[-c] == ic1 , y'''[c] == - ic1

Comment: Hi again. This morning I tried to solve my equation with the first part of your answer. Unfortunately my computer is still working on it an I do not think it will finish. But the Code I used should be all right.  
    `sol1 = DSolve[{y''''[x] + a y[x] == 0, y''[-c] == ic0, y''[c] == ic0 ,
     y'''[-c] == ic1 , y'''[c] == - ic1
    }, y[x], x];       

    Simplify[ComplexExpand[y[x] /. sol1[[1, 1]]], {a > 0, 
  ic0 \[Element] Reals, ic1 \[Element] Reals, c \[Element] Reals}]`

Comment: I got the first part of your answer running but the function y[x] still has complex values. All boundary conditions are set Reals. Using my boundary conditions yields: `sol1 = DSolve[{y''''[x] + a y[x] == 0, y''[-c] == ic0, y''[c] == ic0 ,
     y'''[-c] == ic1 , y'''[c] == - ic1
    }, y[x], x]; sol2 = Simplify[
  sol1, {a > 0, ic0 -> 1, ic1 -> 2, c -> 3, x \[Element] Reals}]; sol3 = ComplexExpand[y[x] /. sol2[[1, 1]]]; sol4 = Simplify[
  sol3, {a > 0, ic0 \[Element] Reals, ic1 \[Element] Reals, 
   c \[Element] Reals, x \[Element] Reals}, TimeConstraint -> 1000]`

Answer (score 4):

I think that some of your statements depend on the details. For instance some of the parameters `C[]` can be complex numbers if you choose `a<0` :

```
parS = Solve[{y1''[-c] == ic0, y1''[c] == ic0, y1'''[-c] == ic1, 
    y1'''[c] == -ic1}, {C[5], C[6], C[7], C[8]}] // Simplify;
parFS = Solve[{y1''[-c] == ic0, y1''[c] == ic0, y1'''[-c] == ic1, 
    y1'''[c] == -ic1}, {C[5], C[6], C[7], C[8]}] // FullSimplify

parS /. {a -> -2, c -> 10, ic0 -> 1, ic1 -> -1} // N
parFS /. {a -> -2, c -> 10, ic0 -> 1, ic1 -> -1} // N

(* {{C[5] -> -0.35876 - 2.498*10^-15 I,  C[6] -> -0.35876 - 2.498*10^-15 I, 
     C[7] -> 2.27596*10^-15 - 0.358762 I, C[8] -> -2.27596*10^-15 + 0.358762 I}}

   {{C[5] -> -0.35876 + 5.10703*10^-15 I, C[6] -> -0.35876 + 5.10703*10^-15 I, 
     C[7] -> 2.35922*10^-15 - 0.358762 I, C[8] -> -2.19269*10^-15 + 0.358762 I}} *)
```

Besides this point you can get the solution to your problem in one line and indeed it seems a real function (apart from numerics) :

```
sol[a_, ic0_, ic1_, c_, x_] = y[x] /. DSolve[{y''''[x] + a y[x] == 0, y''[-c] == ic0, 
     y''[c] == ic0, y'''[-c] == ic1, y'''[c] == -ic1}, y[x], x][[1]] ;

Plot[Im[sol[-2.0, 1.0, -1.0, 10., x]], {x, -10., 10.}]
Plot[Re[sol[-2.0, 1.0, -1.0, 10., x]], {x, -10., 10.}]
```

[image: Im]
[image: Re]

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer.
I forgot to give the download link for my notebook. it can be downloaded under:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4920002/DGL_4th_Order_with_own_solution.nb

I also get this behaviour in the symbolic calculation (in the notebook y3[x] is Real and y4[x] is complex). 

Also for a>0 I get complex constants